# ASP.NET Is there a way to add two "OnItemCommand" to my asp:repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, linkbutton

I have two button with different commands

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbEditDetails" Text="Edit..." runat="server" CommandName="EditDetails" CssClass="EditAdults" CommandArgument=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "number_slept") & "-" & DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "booking_ref")  %>></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:LinkButton ID="lbSubmitDetails" Text="Submit..." Visible="false" runat="server" CommandName="SubmitDetails" CssClass="SubmitAdults" CommandArgument=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "booking_ref")  %>></asp:LinkButton>
```

And my repeater has

```
<asp:Repeater id="dgBookings" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemDB" OnItemCommand="EditDetails">
```

But i need to run `SubmitDetails` when that button is clicked and `EditDetails` when that button is clicked.

Any ideas

Thanks

Jamie

**UPDATE**

My repeater

```
<asp:Repeater id="dgBookings" runat="server" 
OnItemDataBound="ItemDB" OnItemCommand="ItemCommand">
```

My Sub commands

```
Sub ItemCommand(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal e as RepeaterCommandEventArgs)

If e.CommandName = "EditDetails" Then
    EditDetails()   <---- This is where it's dying
Else If e.CommandName = "SubmitDetails" Then 
    SubmitDetails()
End If

End Sub

Sub EditDetails(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal e as RepeaterCommandEventArgs)

Dim strPassedItems = e.CommandArgument

Dim strNumberSlept As String = e.CommandArgument.Split("-"C)(0)
Dim strPassedBookingRef As String = e.CommandArgument.Split("-"C)(1)

CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlEditAdults"), dropdownlist).Visible = True
CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlEditChildren"), dropdownlist).Visible = True

End Sub
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong as I'm getting this error

`Argument not specified for parameter 'e' of 'Public Sub EditDetails(Sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs)'.`

Thanks

Jamie

**UPDATE**

```
Sub ItemCommand(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal e as RepeaterCommandEventArgs)

If e.CommandName = "EditDetails" Then
    EditDetails(sender,e)
Else If e.CommandName = "SubmitDetails" Then 
    SubmitDetails()
End If

End Sub
```

`sender,e` was all i needed to put in.

Thanks

Jamie

Comment: Yeah, you aren't passing the parameters to yuor 'EditDetails' function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing a general OnItemCommand event handler and deciding which method to run based on the CommandName property of the button that was clicked:

```
protected void itemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "EditDetails")
        {
            EditDetails();
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "SubmitDetails")
        {
            SubmitDetails();
        }
    }
}
```

and setting the repeater tag to:

```
<asp:Repeater id="dgBookings" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemDB" OnItemCommand="itemCommand">
```

Comment: I adapted what you gave me by adding `sender,e` into the brackets of `EditDetails` Thanks for the help

Comment: Instead of sending (sender, e) into the methods, I'd probably only pass the values you need as parameters, it makes the methods easier to test.